# In swift, why is UIlabel optional?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, option-type

Looking at this,

```
    @IBOutlet weak var label1 : UILabel!
```

Why is UILabel an optional? The fact that I established a IBOutlet connection to that UILabel means that the UILabel DEFINATELY exists, and wouldn't be nil. So why is it an optional `UIlabel?` and not `UILabel`?

Comment: First of all its IBOutlet and not IBAction. And it is because if you don't connect outlet in xib it will return you nil value for that label.

Comment: How  you imagine weak non-optional properties?

Comment: Why is there an IBAction on a UILabel?

Comment: Bad example. I should have used outlet,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's becouse non-optional variables have to be initialized in constructor and leave all lifecicle.

IBOutlets are weak also, what means it can become nil while e.g. view contoller are still alive.

Comment: If I may ask one more question, do all weak variables HAVE to be optional in Swift?

Comment: Yes, because they can change to nil while lifecicle.

Answer (score 1):

This is about how The View Controller life cycle actually works into play.
Let's be known of Model, View, and Controllers, before proceeding.

The View Controller object itself gets instantiated before the view is loaded i.e. your label. During this time, since *view is not even loaded*, there is no *reference* to the label, as it still needs to be created from storyboard.

For this reason, the object becomes nil for a pretty short unnoticable moment. And, when the view is loaded: `ViewController`, `viewDidLoad()`, then only the labels reference is assigned to the variable.

This outlines a short description on why optionals are really used in iOS.